# listen for Runtime.exec() events

Tags: java, kotlin, process

I have a function that executes a String as an command with the following piece of code:

```
fun String.runAsCommand() : String {
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this)
    if (!process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        process.destroy()
        throw RuntimeException("execution timed out: $this")
    }
    if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw RuntimeException("execution failed with code ${process.exitValue()}: $this")
    }

    return process.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
}
```

However this code outputs the command output once everything is done. But the process in question is actually a long process that takes up to 40 seconds, and gradually outputs status to the console. How do I intercept these echo's/console logs with some kind of listener construction?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), and start another thread that reads the process's stdout (which is your input).

I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but here's some code I came up with to do something very similar.  (In my case, the process wrote to its stdout and stderr, so I needed to read them both — but I didn't need to see them until the process finished.  I also needed to return the process's exit status along with both of those, and to handle timeout.  I didn't need to send anything to the process's stdin, though; if you needed that, you'd have to extend it.)

```
/**
* Runs a system command and captures its output (and stderr).
*
* @param command The program name and any arguments.
* @param workingDir The working directory of the process, or `null` for the same as this process.
* @param timeoutSecs Maximum time to wait for it to finish, in seconds.  (Default is 5 mins.)
* @param throwOnFailure Whether to throw a [ProcessFailedException] if it returns a non-zero exit value.
* @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the command is empty.
* @throws SecurityException if a security manager prevented creation of the process or a redirection.
* @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the OS doesn't support process creation.
* @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
* @throws ProcessTimedOutException if the timeout expires before the process finishes.
* @throws ProcessFailedException if the process returns a non-zero exit status.
*/
fun runProcess(vararg command: String, workingDir: File? = null, timeoutSecs: Long = 300,
                throwOnFailure: Boolean = true): ProcessResult {
    val proc = ProcessBuilder(*command)
                .directory(workingDir)
                .start()

    // Must read both output and error, else it can deadlock.

    class StreamReader(val stream: InputStream, val result: StringBuilder) : Runnable {
        override fun run() = stream.bufferedReader().use { s ->
            while (true)
                result.appendln(s.readLine() ?: break)
        }
    }

    val output = StringBuilder()
    Thread(StreamReader(proc.inputStream, output)).start()
    val error = StringBuilder()
    Thread(StreamReader(proc.errorStream, error)).start()

    val exited = proc.waitFor(timeoutSecs, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    if (!exited)
        throw ProcessTimedOutException("${command[0]} timed out!", timeoutSecs, output.toString(), error.toString())
    val exitValue = proc.exitValue()
    if (exitValue != 0 && throwOnFailure)
        throw ProcessFailedException("${command[0]} failed: $error", exitValue, output.toString(), error.toString())
    return ProcessResult(exitValue, output.toString(), error.toString())
}

/** Thrown if a process doesn't finish within the timeout period. */
class ProcessTimedOutException(msg: String, val timeoutSecs: Long, val output: String, val error: String) : Exception(msg)

/** Thrown if a process returns a non-zero code. */
class ProcessFailedException(msg: String, val exitValue: Int, val output: String, val error: String) : Exception(msg)

/** Returned if a process completes. */
class ProcessResult(val exitValue: Int, val output: String, val error: String)
```

Comment: This does not work, it will still output the results of the process once the complete process is done

Comment: As I said, my code is doing something _similar_ — probably not exactly what you want.  (Though you don't give any details, so it's hard to be sure.)  But that should illustrate the general idea; and maybe you can see how you might adapt the StreamReader there.

Comment: After doing some digging, i think its a problem with the actual command. It's a C++ program that calls printf() instead of println() - I think

Comment: Calling `printf()` isn't necessarily a problem in itself — that's how it always used to be done.  But `stdout` is usually line-buffered, so if those calls aren't including `\n` line separators, then it probably won't be `flush()`ing the stream, and some or all of the output may be stuck in a buffer within that process and not yet available to your Kotlin program.  (You could try redirecting its output to stderr, which is usually unbuffered, but I don't know if that would work.)

Comment: Hmmm that is weird then because the printf() *does* include a \n at the end of the statement

https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/blob/master/src/libslic3r/PrintBase.hpp#L289

Comment: If you run the program directly, from the command-line, do you see the output appear ‘as it happens’?  If so, a Kotlin/Java program should be able to see the output in the same way.

Comment: I do see it as it happens. But for example example when piping the output to a file with ">" it also appears in the file only when the process is completly done. While a ping 127.0.0.1 > status.txt it writes to the file every second 'as it happens'